# what is the header library for JSON in dart language

Tags: dart

what is the header library for JSON in dart language?
I need to parse from string and convert it into map.

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse('{"x":1, "y":2}');
```

what is the header library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse JSON, you import `dart:convert` and use [`json.decode`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-convert/JsonCodec/decode.html) (or [`jsonDecode`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html), which is a just a shorthand for the former).